# End to end page rendering time for performance test jmeter

Tags: jmeter, rendering, performance-testing

My requirement is Overall response time, end to end time including rendering of page in browser should be 3sec . I have to execute Load test for 200 users. So in this case, the response time displayed in JMeter wont be end to end response time right. So during Load test execution , if i execute selenium functional automation scrip during 200 user load test ,whatever time we capture in selenium will that be end to end response time including rendering time? Or JMeter load test response time will be end to end response time?
Can someone please guide me if this is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/index.html):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So JMeter's response time is the time to get the last byte of the response from the server, it doesn't "render" the page at all so if you're looking for that metric as well - stick to Selenium tests (you might want to use i.e. [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) to know what exact rendering time is)

JMeter can be integrated with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)